# Google Cloud Functions "trigger-bucket" is not working as expected

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I made a simple Cloud Function, which is supposed to log details of file operations in a Cloud Storage bucket.

I deployed it with the following command: `gcloud functions deploy bucket_logger --runtime=python37 --memory=256 --region=us-east1 --entry-point=bucket_logger_function --trigger-bucket=[BUCKET_NAME]`

```
def bucket_logger_function(data, context):
    id = context.event_id
    type = context.event_type

    print('Event ID: ' + id)
    print('Event Type: ' + type)

    if type == 'google.storage.object.finalize':
            print('File created: ' + data['name'])
    elif type == 'google.storage.objects.delete':
            print('File deleted: ' + data['name'])
    elif type == 'google.storage.objects.metadataUpdate':
            print('Metadata updated: ' + data['name'])
    else:
            print('File archived: ' + data['name'])
```

I expect the function to trigger whenever I upload, delete, archive and update the metadata of any object within my bucket, but it is only triggered when a file is uploaded.

What could I be missing? The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying/filesystem#background_function_example) doesn't mention anything specific about this, it claims that the aforementioned operations would work.

Answer (score 2):

Have a closer look to the documentation:

> Using the flags --trigger-resource MY_RESOURCE and --trigger-event MY_EVENT is the most explicit way to specify a trigger for a background function. However, gcloud provides shorthands for Pub/Sub and Cloud Storage:

It's *shorhands*. Thus, that performs choice for you implicitly. For knowing more what the command do, I recommend you to use the option `--log-http` for viewing the http call that perform gcloud. For this command, there is a lot and at a moment, I got this

```
==== request start ====
uri: https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<MyProject>/locations/us-central1/functions?alt=json
method: POST
== headers start ==
b'Authorization': --- Token Redacted ---
b'accept': b'application/json'
b'accept-encoding': b'gzip, deflate'
b'content-length': b'903'
b'content-type': b'application/json'
b'user-agent': b'google-cloud-sdk gcloud/293.0.0 command/gcloud.functions.deploy invocation-id/480b4938d2e1469bab2e1a236c5ac53a environment/devshell environment-version/None interactive/True from-script/False python/3.7.3 term/screen (Linux 4.1
9.112+)'
== headers end ==
== body start ==
{"eventTrigger": {"eventType": "google.storage.object.finalize", "resource": "projects/_/buckets/<myBucket>"}, ....
```

You can see `"eventType": "google.storage.object.finalize"`, thus the behavior that you see is the correct one. Only when a file is finalized and event is triggered to your function. This choice has been made for you.

Now, how to solve your use case. 2 ways

- Deploy 4 Cloud Functions, one for each event type (finalize, delete, metadata update and  archive) (not my favorite recommendation, see bellow)
- Create one PubSub topic. Create 4, one for each event type, [pubsub notification on Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reporting-changes#enabling). And then plug your function on the pubsub topic `--trigger-topic=...` instead of `--trigger-bucket=...`

Answer (score 1):

I tried the approach of enabling Pub/Sub notifications, I modified your code, but I'm missing the attribute section which should contain the contentType.

```
def bucket_logger_function(event, context):
    import base64
    import json

    # Print Event Type and Event ID
    print('Event ID: ' + context.event_id)
    print('Event Type: ' + context.event_type)

    # Print Attributes  <-- This is the part that fails
    attributes = base64.b64decode(event['attributes']).decode('utf-8')
    print(attributes['eventType'])

    # Print Payload
    payload = json.loads(base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8'))
    print(payload['name'])
    print(payload['bucket'])
```

I guess that if you get the hang of parsing the attributes you'd be good to go to apply some logic on the event type.